# Remove Table View Cell from Table View with if statement

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift3

How do I remove a static table view cell by doing a if statement like this:

---

if ____ {

**remove static cell**

} else {

**keep cell in tableview**

}

---

The bolded part is what I need the code for. I searched the internet for an answer, but I could not find one. Thanks for the help! I'm using Swift 3

Comment: Strictly spoken a ***static*** cell is supposed to be hard-coded in Interface Builder and could not be removed.

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure to change cells to have Dynamic Properties, because static cells are hard-coded.
Second, you don't need an else statement. If the condition is true, delete the cell, otherwise do nothing. To delete a cell, use a function:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
  if editingStyle == .delete {
  print("Cell deleted")
  // delete any additional data from containers like arrays or dictionaries if needed
  self.tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath], with: .automatic)
  }
}
```

Comment: @NedimKurbeggović Thanks! Quick question, where do I set which cell is to be deleted? I can't find it in the code

Answer (score 0):

If this is a static tableview you can't remove a cell. If you attempt to you'll probably fall into all sorts of issues. Your best solution is to set the cell's height to zero and hide it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt:indexPath)
    if indexPath == cellToHide {
        cell.isHidden = true
    }
    return cell
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if indexPath == cellToHide {
        return 0
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, heightForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```